# SPSS insert treats a warning as an error

Tags: spss

Is it true that SPSS INSERT procedure treats warnings the same way as errors? I am running the INSERT procedure with `ERROR = STOP` keyword. The execution of the procedure stops after the first warning.

I would say it is a strange behaviour. For example, R `source` function stops the execution of the script only on errors, not on warnings.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't always obvious which output indicates a warning and which an error, since both warnings and errors appear in a Warnings block.  For example, if you run this code using the employee data.sav file shipped with Statistics,

missing values jobcat (1 thru 10).
desc variables=jobcat.

it will generate a Warning block that says

Warnings
No statistics are computed because there are no valid cases.

But if you retrieve the error level, which requires programmability, you will see that this is a level 3 error.  Warnings are assigned error level 2.  Warnings do not stop a command from running while higher levels do.

Levels 3, 4, and 5 are considered errors, although level 5, Catastrophic error, would be hard to report, since it means that the SPSS Processor has crashed.

Comment: Does it mean I should eliminate all potential warnings before inserting a syntax? I would like to insert a syntax with keyword `ERROR = STOP`, so the execution stops on the first error.

Comment: And one more comment. What I have seen, warnings are printed as pivot tables, but errors as a log entry. I thought it should be obvious to indicate is it a warning or an error. I am on SPSS 20.